# Order of inertia group on Lang

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $A$ be a Dedeking ring with field of fraction $K$, $L$ be a Galois extension of $K$, $B$ the integral clousure of $A$ in $L$, $\mathfrak p$ a prime ideal of $A$ and $\mathfrak P$ a prime ideal of $B$ lying above $\mathfrak p$, $\bar B=B/\mathfrak P$ and $\bar A=A/\mathfrak p$ the residue fields.
Let $G_{\mathfrak P}$ the decomposition group at $\mathfrak P$, $\phi:\sigma\to\bar\sigma$ the group homomorphism of $G_{\mathfrak P}$ onto the Galois group of $\bar B/\bar A$ (recall that $\bar B/\bar A$ is normal).
The kernel of this homomorphism is the inertia group $T_{\mathfrak P}$.

The following argument shows that the order of $T_{\mathfrak P}$ is $e[\bar B:\bar A]_i$ where $e$ is the ramification index of $\mathfrak P|\mathfrak p$ and $[\bar B:\bar A]_i$ is the inseparability degree.
Since $\phi$ is onto we have $(G_{\mathfrak P}:T_{\mathfrak P})=[\bar B:\bar A]_s$ where $[\bar B:\bar A]_s$ denote the separability degree.
Thus $(T_{\mathfrak P}:1)=(G_{\mathfrak P}:1)/[\bar B:\bar A]_s$.
On the other hand the order of $G_{\mathfrak P}$ equals $ef$ where $f$ is the residue class field degree $[\bar B:\bar A]=f$ (see Lang Algebraic number theory Corollary 3 of Prop. 21 page 26). Since $[\bar B:\bar A]=[\bar B:\bar A]_s[\bar B:\bar A]_i$ the formula holds.

On the other hand on his Algebraic number theory Corollary 3 of Prop. 21 page 26, Lang say that the inertia group has order $e$.
If my argumentation is correct this implies that $\bar B/\bar A$ is separable, but this is not true, in general.

So where is the mistake?

Comment: Doesn't the "$\phi$ is onto" part use Proposition 14 of §5, which requires $\mathfrak p$ to be maximal?

Comment: Yes, but in a Dedekind ring each prime ideal is maximal, see paragraph 6 chapter I.

Comment: Each non-zero prime ideal is maximal. At any rate, @f.lucchini, you're correct, in general the order of inertia is e times the inseparable degree of the residue extension. I can't see where Lang makes any assumption that would imply that the residue extension is separable (e.g. that the residue fields of the DD in question are perfect), so, I guess it's an oversight on his part. 

Comment: Do you know an example of $A$ and $B$ such that $\bar B/\bar A$ is not separable?

Comment: In order to conclude that B is a Dedekind ring you need the residual extension $\bar B/\bar A$ to be separable, I think.

Comment: @Tommaso No, you don't. The integral closure of a Dedekind domain in a finite extension of its quotient field is always Dedekind. @f.lucchini Take $A=k[[T]]$, where k is any imperfect field. This is a complete discrete valuation ring with residue field k. Let $\bar{f}\in k[X]$ be an inseparable monic irreducible polynomial, $f$ a monic lift of $\bar{f}$, and put $B=A[X]/(f)$. This is a discrete valuation ring, finite over $B$, whose residue field is $k[X]/(\bar{f})$, so, inseparable over $k$. 

Comment: @Keenan Kidwell: In your example, $L/K$ is not a Galois extension, in general. For if $k=\mathbb F_p(Y^p)$ where $p$ is prime and $Y$ indeterminate over $\mathbb F_p$, $f(X)=X^p−Y^p$ then $Y\in L$ is puerly inseparable over $K$ since $Y^p\in k$.

Comment: @Keenan. Thanks for correcting me. Hey lucchini, did you take a look to Serre's Corps Locaux I \S 7? It might shed light on your question.

Comment: @f.lucchini Sorry, I thought you just wanted a finite extension of Dedekind domains with an inseparable residue extension.

Comment: @Tommaso: Now I'm reading Lang, but my next reading is Serre.
Thank'you for your suggestion.